# The Shapes of CSS - the star. How it works?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image]

Below is the code of [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/). I want to understand the CSS properties in detail here. How does the shape in CSS work? The pseudo CSS, the borders and the CSS3 properties. Need to clear some concept regarding core CSS properties.

```css
#star-five {
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
}
#star-five:before {
   border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

}
#star-five:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

Comment: Basically there are three triangles, each rotated differently. Inspect the elements to see them.

Comment: Try playing around with color and width properties etc to get the best learning experience!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a better visualisation

```css
#star-five {
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);
}
#star-five:before {
   border-bottom: 80px solid blue;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   content: '';
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);

}
#star-five:after {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid green;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);
   content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

3 triangles made using CSS borders, that are rotated to be in the position of a star.

The other two triangles are just the before/after pseudo elements of the star-five div.

Answer (score 1):

The star is shaped out of three triangles which are moved to the right angle and position:

Triangle 1:

```css
#star-five {
   margin: 50px 0;
   position: relative;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right:  100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
   border-left:   100px solid transparent;
   -moz-transform:    rotate(35deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(35deg);

}
```

```html
<div id="star-five"></div>
```

Triangle 2:

```
    #star-five {
    border-bottom: 80px solid red;
   border-left: 30px solid transparent;
   border-right: 30px solid transparent;
   position: absolute;
   height: 0;
   width: 0;
   top: -45px;
   left: -65px;
   display: block;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-35deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-35deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-35deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-35deg);
    }
    <div id="star-five"></div>
```

Triangle 3:

```
    #star-five {
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   color: red;
   top: 3px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 0px;
   height: 0px;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 70px solid red;
   border-left: 100px solid transparent;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-70deg);
   -moz-transform:    rotate(-70deg);
   -ms-transform:     rotate(-70deg);
   -o-transform:      rotate(-70deg);

    }
    <div id="star-five"></div>
```

The blank `content` property in css creates a new `div` element with nothing in it and with `before` and `after`, you place this element before or after you've selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
#star-five {
  border-right:  100px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 70px  solid red;
  border-left:   100px solid transparent;
}
```

This creates a rectangle pointing upwards which afterwards is rotated by 35 degrees

```
#star-five:after{}
```

is bascically the same it is also a rectangle (same size like the main one) but rotated and moved differently

```
#star-five:before{}
```

is a little bit different is it a smaller rectangle (you can change the size of each rectangle by changing each border thicket

```
border-bottom: 70px solid red; (change 70px here for example)
```

afterwards every rectangle is moved to a position to form a star
it is important that :before and :after have content: ''